# Import-Csv: The member "Client Memory" is already present

Tags: powershell, runtime-error, powershell-4.0

I'm getting an error when running `Import-Csv`: `The member "Client Memory" is already present.` The command I am running is:

```
Import-Csv "FilePath" | Select -ExpandProperty "SystemCondition"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two columns with the same heading, in this case the duplicate name is `Client Memory`. Each column should have a unique name.